# Load urlrequest in the wkwebview when app is in background state

Tags: ios, wkwebview, nsurlrequest, ios-background-mode

Is there any way to load a request in WKWebView when the app is in a background state?

I need to load a request and then will need to read javascript from a certain redirected page.

Currently, wkwebview kind of going in pause mode if the app is in the background or not loading at all.
If I open the app, then wkwebview completes its loading immediately.

Does anyone know anything about this?

I am not writing complete details about the website or request URL. I just need to have a way or direction to render wkwebview content on request load when the app is in the background state.

I hope my problem is clear to you.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, did you find any solution to it?